# Can't Compile After Adding Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods, back4app

My iOS app has Parse. I installed it using CocoaPods. On two classes I have added `@import Parse;` AppDelegate is one just to initialize the Parse server. Everything is found, there are no error messages. Yet when I build, it fails and only says:

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFObject, referenced from:
       in FinalRegistration.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse, referenced from:
       in AppDelegate.o
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_ParseClientConfiguration, referenced from:
       in AppDelegate.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have gone to navigator and clicked on Pods and both Parse and Bolts are there, both are set to Xcode 13.0, both have deployment targets set to 13.0. Xcode sees everything as when I type it autocompletes the code for Parse with no problems, it simply just won't build.

Here are some images of my setup and Podfile

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]